# Switch case requiring two calls to actually work

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I have a switch within a while loop with many cases to run basic statistical analysis on a set of numbers. We're working on replacing the simple array of values with a map of arrays of doubles for multiple datasets that the user can add to. I have added an "add" case, and it can successfully add to the map... on every *other* run. So, when I write "add dataset 1 2 3 4 5" into the scanner, nothing happens, but if I write that into the scanner again, it will add successfully. Here's the important bit of code, let me know what you can make of it. getOption() is a method that gets a string via a scanner, splits it into individual words, and enter those words into an array of strings. The format of input is "case keyForMap valuesForMap". I know we shouldn't assume the user will follow this format, but we're letting it slide for this assignment.  getValues() takes the numbers in the array, parses them to double, and adds them to a new array of doubles, which is returned.

```
HashMap<String,double[]> dataMap = new HashMap();
...
public void driver(){
    Stats s = new Stats(data);
    String[] options = getOption();
    while (!"quit".equals(options[0])){
    switch (options[0]) {
        case "add": if (getOption().length < 2){
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        dataMap.put(options[1], getValues(options));
                    }
                    break;

        case "summary": //Arrays.toString(dataMap.entrySet().toArray());
                        System.out.println(dataMap.containsKey("dsn"));
                        break;
        case "quit": return;
        default: System.out.println(options[0] + " is not a legal option");
    }
    options = getOption();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does a break inside the then part of an if statement break out of the switch? Even if it does, wouldn't `if (!...) {...} break;` be a bit cleaner?

Comment: And what's the point of handling "quit" in the switch? You're already checking for "quit" as the loop termination condition.

Comment: all good points, I added that quit case a while ago and forgot about it. Also, the if/else bit seems to work, as without it, users running just "add" with no other values would get negative array size errors, as getValues() creates an array with the length of the user's input array - 2.

Comment: You mention it working the second time. If you type something different the second time, which one actually gets executed? The first or the second?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor it does break the switch.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor good point!! I just learned it adds the _first_, not the second. Interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `if (getOption().length < 2)` with `if (options.length < 2)`. Having the method call there means you're fetching a whole new line of input instead of using the one you already have, and then throwing it away after checking only its length.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, that clears up a lot about method calls for me. Calling getValues(options) is fine though, because the options array hasn't changed, correct?

Comment: @Qdhcjv Yes, and if getValues neither modifies options (building a new array based on options doesn't count) nor gets input from elsewhere it would even be safe - though wasteful - to call it multiple times.